# Angular 2 Two way binding with [disabled]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have an input with `[disabled]` depending upon the `ngModel` of another input. Initially `[disabled]` is working properly but not when we change the dependant input value, the `[disabled]` property is not working. How to apply two binding on `[disabled]` property?

Following is the code snippet.

```
<select [ngModel]="isDisabled" (ngModelChange)="isDisabled=$event">
<option value="0">Disabled</option>
<option value="0">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

This model `isDisabled` is changed correctly. I could see the value change like this in template `{{isDisabled}}`. But not reflected in the `[disabled]` property of the select box.

```
<select [ngModel]="userInput" [disabled]="isDisabled">
<option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try using ng-disabled

Comment: @O.Paquay this is Angular not AngularJS(Angular 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem was you were using same `value` 0 for both option. But even if you change them to `1` & `0` respectively for `Enable` & `Disable`. It will not gonna work because `value` attribute stores values as `'0'`(string '0') & `'1'`(string `1`) (in short stringify value of it).

You could easily solve this dataType issue of value by using `ngValue` attribute binding.

```
<select [ngModel]="isDisabled" (ngModelChange)="isDisabled=$event">
  <option [ngValue]="1">Disabled</option>
  <option [ngValue]="0">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SQNjvRey7XJWiDVqdRiz?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a name attribute to the input and make the ng-mode two-way binding by wrapping up with parenthesis also. no need to use the `ngModelChange` for this purpose

```
<select [(ngModel)]="isDisabled"  name='isDisabled'>
        <option value="0">Disabled</option>
        <option value="1">Enabled</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="userInput" [disabled]="isDisabled == '0'" name='userInput'>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question, both option values are `0`.

You'll want to ensure that one is `true`, with the other being `false`

---

Component:

```
component class {
    myVar = false
}
```

Template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myVar">
    <option value="true">...</option
    <option value="false">...</option
</select>

<select [disabled]="myVar">
    <option>...</option
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `true\false` for `[disabled]` it will save your function comparator, and use 2-way binding directly.

Like:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="isDisabled">
        <option value="true">Disabled</option>
        <option value="false">Enabled</option>
</select>

<select [ngModel]="userInput" [disabled]="isDisabled">
     <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

[See Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DQ2fIeIv1pBZlYCY4mhQ?p=preview)